# how to double the resolution of the map?

Tags: ros, resolution, pgm, sbpl, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i did the [SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM),got a [map](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1bndaN6Z)( width :576,height:512) and  a [yaml file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1jGsvANO) that goes with my  pgm map. Its resolution is 0.05,but the SBPL Lattice planner has a map resolution 0.025,  i want  to  change  my map's  resolution  is 0.025.There has been a  [similar problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/165846/pgm-resolution-problem/?comment=204490#comment-204490)  .

**Question**:   what should  i do  to my pgm map  with the gimp software to change my pgm map's resolution?

Thanks for  your help !!

[my_map.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14258168323007432.png)

[my_map_yaml.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14258168471365504.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204499/how-to-double-the--resolution-of-the-map-?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2015-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Gimp, use the Image -> Scale Image tool, and double the X and Y size of the image.

In your map.yaml, set the resolution to 0.025:

```
resolution: 0.025
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-03-10**:
thanks @ahendrix,it's very very clear.By the way ,there is  a [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/178972/about-resolution-on-yaml/) , @dornhege suggests that   we should not change the resolution after building a map,what do you  see this  idea ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-10**:
You cannot change the resolution **without** scaling the image also. Unless this is not possible I would usually just rebuilt the map with the target resolution.

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-03-11**:
Thanks very much , you and ahendrix  are  very  kind.^-^

**Comment by [Tarantula-7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26921/tarantula-7/) on 2017-04-02**:
@jxl Have you try to generate your own primitive file(*.mprim) with your resolution in SBPL??? May be it works